# Using XPath with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, xpath, casperjs

I am using CasperJS to test my frontend, and a new element of "foo" is created with the name "Brand New Name" and there are already existing 'foo' elements. I need to use XPath to select the specific element with the correct name so I can test if it exists using Casper.

This is what I'm doing currently:

```
this.test.assertExists(x('//*[@class="foo" and text()="Brand New Name"]'), 'new thing exists')
```

But this is not finding what I want, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

This is the Casper.JS failure message I receive, even though the `xPath` selector looks correct.

```
FAIL new category exists
#    type: assertExists
#    file: ../../../foo/test/casper/foo_manager/new_category.js
#    subject: false
#    selector: {"type":"xpath","path":"//*[@class=\"foo\" and contains(text(), \"Brand New Category\")]"
```

I have realized that there is actually a `span` in the element I am trying to select. I have tried to account for this, but I just can't get the `xPath` CasperJS selector to work. I have updated the `xPath` selector to a `contains` and it still won't work.

The selector looks like this:

```
this.test.assertExists(x('//*[@class="foo" and contains(text(), "Brand New Category")]'), 'new category exists')
```

The element in question looks like this:

```
<a href='#' class='foo' id='foo-bar'>
  Brand New Category
  <span>some text</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your test should pass if you try this:

**HTML** (*index.html*)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CasperJS and XPath</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="foo">Foo</li>
    <li class="foo">Bar</li>
    <li class="foo">Brand New Name</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** (*xpath.js*)

```
casper.test.begin('CasperJS and XPath', 1, function (test) {
  var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

  casper.start('index.html', function () {
    this.test.assertExists(x('//*[@class="foo" and text()="Brand New Name"]'), 'new thing exists');
  });

  casper.run(function () {
    test.done();
  });
});
```

**Command**

```
casperjs test xpath.js
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Badacadabra, I have updated my question and am still having problems if you could take a look? thanks

Comment: I have tested your new HTML structure with your new XPath selector and it is working. Please make sure the element is loaded when you test it with Casper. This may be a timing issue...

Comment: the element is definitely loaded, I can screenshot casper and it displays. Also I changed the test to search for a specific id instead of by class and text, and it passed, but I still can't get it to pass by using class and text